# How to limit the scope of the variables used in a script?

Tags: r, scope

Let's say I've written an R script which uses some variables. When I run it, those variables clutter the global R environment. To prevent this, how do I limit the scope of variables used in a script to that script only? Note: I know that one way is to use functions, are there any other ways?

Comment: Can you give a short example of an R script that modifies your global environment in the way you would like to prevent?

Comment: Sure: {n <- 1; for (i in 1:10) n <- n*i; cat("n = ", n);}. This will add variables i and n to the global enviroment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use the `local=TRUE` argument to `source` and evaluate `source` somewhere other than your global environment.  Here are a few ways to do that (assuming you don't want to be able to access the variables in the script).  `foo.R` just contains `print(x <- 1:10)`.

```
do.call(source, list(file="c:/foo.R", local=TRUE), envir=new.env())
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
ls()
# character(0)

mysource <- function() source("c:/foo.R", local=TRUE)
mysource()
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
ls()
# [1] "mysource"
```

`sys.source` is probably the most straight-forward solution.

```
sys.source("c:/foo.R", envir=new.env())
```

You can also evaluate the file in an attached environment, in case you want to access the variables.  See the examples in `?sys.source` for how to do this.

Comment: Can you show how to deal with what I thought he was requesting .... multiple functions and objects to be encapulated?

Comment: @Dwin: not sure what you mean.  Something like `sys.source` into an environment?

Comment: I imagined that he might want multiple functions that could be somehow accessed inside an environment but wouldn't show up with ls().

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `local` function.

Comment: That's just too obvious ;-)  You still need `local=TRUE` in `source` though.

Comment: @Joshua, that assumes that the user is using source, they could also be doing a copy and paste or using an editor that does a copy/paste behind the scene.  You could wrap the entire script in `local({...})` (or the parts that you want localized) then source or copy/paste (but thanks for pointing out the simple `local=TRUE` for source).

Comment: Excellent point.  When I see "run script" I think `source` or Rscript.