# How to create R functions with private variables?

Tags: r, variables, scope, private

How do I create a set of R functions that all access the same private variable?

Let's say I want to create `readSetting(key)` and `writeSetting(key,value)` functions that both operate on the same hidden list `settings`.  If I try it like so...

```
local( {
  settings <- list()
  readSetting <<- function ( key ) settings[[key]]
  writeSetting <<- function ( key, value ) settings[[key]] = value
} )
```

...then `readSetting` and `writeSetting` are not visible outside of the `local` call.  If I want them to be visible there, I have to first assign

```
readSetting <- writeSetting <- NULL
```

outside the `local` call.  There must be a better way, because my code isn't DRY if I have to say in two different ways which variables are public.

(The context of this work is that I'm developing an R package, and this code will be in an auxiliary file loaded into the main file via `source`.)

This question is related to [How to limit the scope of the variables used in a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275407/how-to-limit-the-scope-of-the-variables-used-in-a-script) but the answers there do not solve my problem.

Comment: You could look at how `knitr` handles its options (which seems to be similar to `base::options`) as an example.

Comment: Maybe I'm a little slow, @Gregor, but I'm having trouble seeing the connection.

Comment: It's about the only package I can think of that has global options that get modified frequently. The chunk options could all be made invisible (more-or-less) if `knitr` didn't export `opts_chunk`.

Comment: Also *"this code will be in an auxiliary file loaded into the main file via source"* doesn't sound to me like good R package practice. I haven't developed many packages so I could be wrong, but this sounds like it would be better implemented as an unexported data object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate somthing like that using R6Class package and the following very rough code:

```
Privates <- R6Class("Privates",
                public=list(
                     readSetting = function(key) {
                       private$settings[[key]]
                     },
                     writeSetting = function(key,value) {
                       private$settings[[key]] <<- value
                     }
                   ),
                private=list(
                  settings = list()
                )
)
a <- Privates$new()
a$writeSetting("a",4)
a$readSetting("a")
```

Directly reading o setting the `a$setting` would not work.

Comment: Looks good. You can also use an environment which is what some of the base R functions do, some of them explicitly. I'm thinking of `stepfun` and `ecdf`, but I suspect this method is more robust, since you should be able to export R6Classes.

Comment: That seems to hit at the heart of what I'm trying to do, but I'm not sure I want to import a whole class package for this one thing.

Comment: It all depends what you want to achieve and why or do you at all really need it private?